# Hosting WCF REST Service as Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, windows-services

I want to create REST WCF Service and Install it as Windows service.
I have created REST WCF Service and I ran that, it is working fine for both xml amd json. 
Below are the code files.
IRestWCFServiceLibrary.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace RestWCFServiceLibrary
{
    // NOTE: If you change the class name "Service1" here, you must also update the             reference to "Service1" in App.config.
    public class RestWCFServiceLibrary : IRestWCFServiceLibrary
    {
        public string XMLData(string id)
        {
            return "Id:" + id;
        }
        public string JSONData(string id)
        {
            return "Id:" + id;
        }
    }
}
```

RestWCFServiceLibrary.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace RestWCFServiceLibrary
{
    // NOTE: If you change the interface name "IService1" here, you must also update the reference to "IService1" in App.config.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestWCFServiceLibrary
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "xml/{id}")]
        string XMLData(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
        string JSONData(string id);
    }
}
```

App.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must     be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="RestWCFServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior"
        name="RestWCFServiceLibrary.RestWCFServiceLibrary">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"     contract="RestWCFServiceLibrary.IRestWCFServiceLibrary" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8001/RestWCFServiceLibrary/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestWCFServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before     deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now I want to host/install it as Windows Service, for that I added Window Service project and gave the reference of the RESR WCF which is created as above. Named the service class as MyRestWCFRestWinSer

MyRestWCFRestWinSer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using RestWCFServiceLibrary;

namespace RestWCFWinService
{
    public partial class MyRestWCFRestWinSer : ServiceBase
    {
        ServiceHost oServiceHost = null;
        public MyRestWCFRestWinSer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            oServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyRestWCFRestWinSer));
            oServiceHost.Open();
        }

       protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (oServiceHost != null)
            {
                oServiceHost.Close();
                oServiceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;

namespace RestWCFWinService
{
    static class Program
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new MyRestWCFRestWinSer() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

And I added project installer, I ran the installer. After running I registered the service from command prompt by using installutil.
Service successfully registered and listed in the Services.
If I start the service it is giving error as "**The RestWCFWinService Service on Local Computer started and the stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs**"

But If I do this using SOAP it is working perfect.

So please anyone help me to install this REST WCF service as Windows service.

Comment: Have you tried with `WebServiceHost` instead of `ServiceHost`?

Comment: @Tim
You mean to say hosting REST WCF as Web Service?

Comment: No - it's already a web service.  I mean use [WebServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webservicehost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which compliments the WCF REST model (it's derived from `ServiceHost`).  Also, check your event viewer to see if there were any errors logged there by the service when it started.

Comment: I'd suggest you're encountering a runtime error which is causing the service to stop.  Most likely it's a configuration error.  Check the EventLog

Comment: @Tim, I understood and made the changes as WebServiceHost instead of ServiceHost and I installed. Still same issue is there. I checked log files also there are no errors.

Comment: @Mick and @Tim
In the Event Viewer Error reported as `Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Service 'RestWCFWinService.MyRestWCFRestWinSer' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.EnsureThereAreNonMexEndpoints(ServiceDescription description)

Comment: @Hanumantha - Did you copy the service model section from your library App.config to the app.config of the Windows Service?

Comment: I don't think you're doing yourself a favour naming the class for the service the same name as the namespace.  I can't see an issue with it, but I simply wouldn't do it because it could cause confusion (like you seem to be having).  Try changing the class name for your service then update the config correspondingly e.g. <service ... name="RestWCFServiceLibrary.LessConfusingService">

Comment: I found the problem, actually configurations are not correct. I took different application and gave the proper configuration and it is working fine.
Thanks @Mick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there are two issues - one of which you have corrected per your comments.

First, you're using `ServiceHost` instead of `WebServiceHost`.  I'm not 100% certain that's part of the problem, but based on your comments (no errors in the Event Viewer when using `ServiceHost`, error when you changed to `WebServiceHost` would seem to indicate it was).

The second issue appears to be related to your configuration file.  You have a WCF service library (a DLL).  By design, DLLs do not use the app.config file included in the project template - they use the config file of the consuming application.  In this case, the Windows Service.  Copy the `<system.serviceModel>` section from your library config file to the app.config file of your Windows service.  Your WCF class library should pick up the endpoint at that point.

Note that the Windows Service config file, once the project is compiled, will be named `MyRestWCFRestWinSer.exe.config`, *not* `App.config`.

Comment: Ya your second point is right, I was missing the app.config file. Now I added to Windows service. Still service not starting and now in Event Viewer error is "Service cannot be started. System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: There is no endpoint behavior named 'web'. (C:\Program Files\Default Company Name\MyRestWCFService\RestWCFWinService.exe.Config line 12)"

Comment: @Hanumantha - Did you copy everything in the `<system.serviceModel>` section over?  It sounds like it's missing the `<endpointBehavior>` you defined in the library app.config.

Comment: Yes I copied the <system.serviceModel> section.
According to me there may be miss match in namespace of service and service name of config. I am not aware how to give config file setting to match the service namespace and other thing.

Comment: Can you update your question and post the config file as you have it for the Windows service?  I don't think it's a namespace issue, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It is same as above config file, actually there was no config file for windows service, I added app.config file and I copy pasted the full app.config file from WCF service which is there above.

Comment: Odd.  The config file looks correct, as does the service name.  Not sure what else to try.  Sorry :(

Comment: I found the problem, actually configurations are not correct. I took different application and gave the proper configuration and it is working fine.
Thanks @Tim

Comment: @Hanumantha can you post correct .config file? I am having the same problem as you did

Comment: @Thomas - If the answer above doesn't solve your problem, you can post it as a new question.  It's likely to get more attention (and an answer) that way.